# Can't get the html render conditionally?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a strange incident in getting the html page rendering conditionally with asp.net core 2.0

```
    <head>
        @{
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
         }
    </head>
    <body>
     @if (user != null)
     {
       <a href="/user/edit/?username=@user.UserName" class="dropdown-toggle">
       <span class="hidden-xs">@user.FullName</span>
                                   </a>
     }
   </body>
```

For this layout, it gives errors: **"The name 'user' does not exist in the current context** It used to work fine in .net core 1.1 and classic asp.net.

However, if I do like this, then it works fine. So strange.

```
<body>
@{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
   if (user != null)
    {
      <a href="/user/edit/?username=@user.UserName" class="dropdown-toggle">
       <span class="hidden-xs">@user.FullName</span>
                               </a>
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't declare variables inside "head" tag. I tried the following and it worked just fine:

```
@{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
}
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
@if (user != null)
{
    <a href="/user/edit/?username=@user.UserName" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <span class="hidden-xs">@user.FullName</span>
    </a>
}
</body>
```

Comment: if I make a breakpoint on header, it does show the right value, but somehow it still causes the error on the body.

Comment: my guess is because razor treat head and body as different "scopes", but when you move the code outside head tag, it becomes global to the current document

Comment: really strange, it's worked in all other versions. Thanks for your sharp eyes :D